# New Wordpress site cache issue with old site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching, redirect

I've replaced an old WP site with a new one, on the same domain.

The root for the previous site was `www.mydomain.com/deploy/` (for whatever reason).

The new site's root is just `www.mydomain.com`.

Now, it appears old visitors who visit the new site for the first time, still end up at `www.mydomain.com/deploy/`. Even though it's a whole new WP installation.

I've set a redirect rule for everything that begins with `deploy/`, gets redirected to `www.mydomain.com`.
However, this causes too many redirects for those affected visitors.

How do I go about forcing their cache to clear?

current `.htaccess` file:

```
Header add "disablevcache" "true"

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^deploy/(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to turn the redirects off, if its still in the same domain that they will eventually findout to acsess your site home instead

Comment: Yes, but for some reason they keep getting redirected to the old `deploy/` path, which results in a 404.

Comment: do u have two install? in / and in /deploy? is the above htacsess the one on the deploy or on the root?

Comment: There is no /deploy/ anymore. It's a whole new installation. That's what baffles me.

Comment: how did u know that your user are redirected to the old one? google anaylics? if so maybe they are the one caching the site on the front page.

Comment: I found out for myself, in the beginning. I cleared my cache and everything was fine. But most people don't know how to clear their cache, and thus can't see the new website. 2 other people I know had the same thing.

Comment: then it will be just fine, give them a few more days. but donno maybe there is another guy who can give more details

Comment: Hmm, so there's no brute force way?

Comment: i think no for my knowlage